# retrieve values from database and display in textbox for the corresponding value selected using drop down in ajax

Tags: php, html, ajax

I have a dropdown list where it lists values fetched from database

```
echo "<select name='training_name' id='training_name' value='' class='form-control' onchange='tr_name()' required><option value=''>Select</option>";
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $dt=date("Y-m-d",strtotime($r['date']));?>
<option value="<?php echo $r['nomination_form_trainer_id'];?>" ><?php echo $r['training_title']."(".$dt.")";?></option>; 
<?php }?>
<?php echo "</select>";
```

I have a input type as textbox

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control txtOnly" id="trainer_name" name="trainer_name" value="" required/>
```

I have my ajax code as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function tr_name()
    {

        var tname= $('#training_name').val();
         var dataString = 'tname=' + tname;
         $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "training_name.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(result){ 
             $("#trainer_name").html(result);
        }
    });

    }
</script>
```

here is my php code for training_name.php

```
<?php require_once 'includes/config.php';

$training_name = $_POST["training_name"];
mysql_select_db("ptlct_training");

    //here, you should test whether employee_detail matches what you expect
    //here, split $employee_detail into $first_name, $last_name and $company_name
    //now you are ready to send the MYSQL query:
    $sql = 'SELECT initiator_name FROM nomination_form_trainer WHERE nomination_form_trainer_id=2';
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    //since you expect a single matching result, you can test for num_rows == 1:
        while ($row =mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $trainer_name = $row['initiator_name'];
        }
    echo $trainer_name;
    ?>
```

I am trying to fetch values I am new to ajax so i couldn't find where I am going wrong.Someone please help me soon.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
var dataString = '&tname=' + tname;
```

check param is passing in php or not .....!

Comment: are u using click function in jquery??

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer by myself

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $("#training_name").change(function(){
    {
        var tname = $('#training_name').val();
         var dataString = 'tname=' + tname;
         $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "training_name.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(result){ 
             $("#trainer_name").val(result);
        }
    });

    }
   });

</script>
```

I have declared the variable inside the function that is why the parameter did not pass properly